# SVG won't render as CSS background-image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to implement a close button using a SVG image as `background-image`. Below is the code I am using:

```
.close-button {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[The data for the image]);
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: center center; 
}

<span class="close-button"></span>
```

You can test it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpfEz).

It becomes a 16 by 16 `span` but the image does not render. Why is this happening? Also, the image is originally black-filled. I want to change its fill to white. Is there any way to achieve this?

So, my questions are:

1. Why doesn't the image render as background?
2. How to change the SVG fill on `:hover`? (given my configuration - available in the link above)

Comment: how does the svg look like?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/cross_mark.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set either the `width` and `height`, or the `viewBox` attribute on the `<svg>`. I would recommend the `viewBox`, because you do not to scale the graphics to fit in. Of course you are free to set all of them, but that easily leads to confusion for your purposes.

Please note, to gain an SVG that fits into each element, do not use `width` and `height` and use `viewBox`. [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html) is a nice explanation for the viewBox.

For the SVG you posted a possible viewBox could roughly be like that:

```
<svg viewBox="16 104 170 170" >
```

I do not know how you generate your SVG but to fix those Issues I use inkscape. Just open the file > document Properties > resize document to content and save.

Than, if you want, open the svg in an text editor, create a such a `viewBox="0 0 <value of width> <value of height>"` and remove the width and height attributes.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have downloaded the SVG from here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/274c/index.htm , so I have taken it already generated.

Comment: well, just increase the size of the span to 300 300 and set the background size to the same values and you will see the cross. The reason why you cannot see it is that you are displaying a region of the graphic where no graphic content is. Open the svg in the browser and look at the region 0 0 16 16, that is just blank. If you cannot modify the svg, it wont work.

Comment: if you have problems to encode the modified svg using base64: http://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the xmlns attribute that specifies the xml namespace that was missing

I changed my svg from:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" id="square" />
</svg>
```

to this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" id="square" />
</svg>
```

then I encoded it using a tool called "URL-encoder for SVG" hosted on github pages  [https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Note: you could also use any url encode tool instead, like "Eric Meyers URL Decoder/Encoder" [https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/][2] but the tool mentioned above does a bit more then just url encoding your SVG, it will for example replace double quotes with single quotes before encoding, which will result in a slightly smaller result (as single quotes don't need to get encoded, compared to double quotes wo do need), the is also a bit more readable which is something I like

and then I was able to use it as background-image, like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
<style>
    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20fill%3D%22%23000%22%20id%3D%22square%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
</body>

</html>
```